# At what time does cron dialy run? (On EC2 Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

So im running an EC2 Ubuntu and i recentlly changed the timezone (using tzselect) of the instance to GTM -03 since this my local time and then i checked /etc/crontab and got:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

According to what i read this should mean that daily runs at 6.25am but i doesnt seem like it. Plus idk if this time applies to the timezone of the instance.

There is no /etc/anacron file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that anacron is not installed on your system and the timezone is correct and the local time is correct, daily.cron in your example will run at 6:25 AM.

If anacron is installed, then you need to look up the variables RANDOM_DELAY and START_HOURS_RANGE to determine the "approximate" time range that daily.cron will run.

Comment: How can i find if anacron is installed? And where should i look for this variables? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you have the file /etc/anacrontab? List installed packages: apt-get list.